# angular5 dynamic compoments parent-chld communication

Tags: angular, dynamic, angular5, angular-directive

I'm implementing the approach described in [the dynamic compoment docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).

I need my dynamic components to be able to emit an event to the parent component and in response the parent component might need to call a method of the child component.

I know how to bind child events to a parent's method when the child component is in the parent's template:

- `@Output() xevent : eventEmitter<string>;` in child
- `<child-comp (xevent)="aParentMethod($event)"` in parent template

However in the dynamic component approach, the parent template contains a directive, which in turn will wrap the dynamically instantiated component.

How can I set @Input and @Output properties on the dynamic component and propagate them from parent to child and vice-versa?

Moreover, how can I have the parent call a method on the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular docs are a little bit outdated as far as dynamic components go. Take a look at `[ngComponentOutlet]` directive introduced in Angular 4. It might simplify your component by a lot.

The simple use case is as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ng-container [ngComponentOutlet]="component"></ng-container>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  // [ngTemplateOutlet] binds to this property, you can set this dynamically!
  component = HelloComponent; 
}
```

More on NgComponentOutlet in the [api documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet).

So this is a good news. The bad news is that there is currently no way to access `@Inputs` and `@Outputs` of the component created this way. You can track this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15360) on github.

In the mean time, some people suggested using [ng-dynamic-component](https://github.com/gund/ng-dynamic-component).

You can also implement the parent/child communication using a shared service:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {CommunicationService} from './communication.service';
import {HelloComponent} from './hello.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <input (keydown.enter)="send(input.value); input.value = ''" #input />
  <ng-container [ngComponentOutlet]="component"></ng-container>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  component = HelloComponent;

  constructor(private communicationService: CommunicationService) {}

  send(val: string) {
    this.communicationService.next(val);
  }
}
```

communication.service.ts

```
import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import  {Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class CommunicationService {
  private messageSource = new Subject();
  message$ = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  next(val: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(val);
  }
}
```

hello.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {CommunicationService} from './communication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>{{ message$ | async }} </h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  message$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private communication: CommunicationService) {
    this.message$ = communication.message$;
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/parent-child-ngcomponentoutlet-comunication)

Comment: NgComponentOutlet removes some boilerplate, but since you cannot access @Input/Output how can parent and child component interact?

Comment: Well, the first thing that comes to mind is through a service https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: To make sure I get the whole picture, AppComponent constructor would take an injected service and so would the child HelloComponent. Or should I use the injector property of NgComponentOutlet?

Comment: @Cec I've edited my answer with parent/child communication using shared service. Please consider accepting/upvoting my answer :) Creating the code samples took a tille bit of time.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed answer, I just noticed the updates you made :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)